# Using browser back button in triggers flash message in CakePHP again

Tags: firefox, cakephp, google-chrome, cakephp-2.0

I just came across a bit of a puzzling situation. My controller action looks like this:

```
public function myaction($eventId = false) {
    if(!$eventId) {
        //list all events
        $data = foo;
    } else {
        if(!$this->Event->findById($eventId) )
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('myerror message', 'flash_frontend_message');
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'myaction'));
        } else {
            // display event information
            $data = foo;
        }
    }
    $this->set($data);
}
```

If I call the function with an $eventId that is not found in the database, it outputs an error message and the user gets redirected back to the list of all events. However lets say I then select an eventId which is valid, view the relevant information and then press the browser back button, the previous flash message gets out put again, even though the URL in this case does not contain the $eventId.

I suppose what happens is that the page gets loaded from the browser cache rather then reloaded. I have tried to avoid storing the view in the cache like this:

```
<!--nocache-->
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<!--/nocache-->
```

but still, the flash message gets displayed.

Any idea how to prevent this behavior? 
Is there perhaps a way to clear the flash after it has been displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are talking about the right cache but trying to fix it with the wrong cache.

```
<!--nocache-->
```

is php/html no cache statements in the file itself. it has nothing to do with the browser cache.
what you need to be doing is setting the right headers.

there is a convinience method in the request object for this exact thing:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#interacting-with-browser-caching

I use it in all my normal frontend actions via AppController:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->response->disableCache();
    ...
}
```

Comment: That totally looks like it should work, but doesn't... I tried three different locations in the action itself, in the controller, and in the AppController, but still it does it. What is even more strange is that Chrome seems to display the error message even when going back from a totally valid request - i.e. First view event list, then go to event.

Comment: your apache/htacess might override some of those headers. try to debug the headers with Firebug (Firefox ext). then you might know why your browser behaves like this.

Comment: That was it... I tested the setup on the production server and it works. The behavior only happened on my local development setup.